# bash: how to source a file keeping backslashes intact

Tags: bash, backslash

In a bash script, I want to to read a configuration file like this one:

```
re=foo\.bar
```

such that, after sourcing that file, the value of $re is foo\.bar. 
When I simply source the file, the backslash gets lost. How can I do this, without quoting the 'foo.bar' in the config file (I want to keep the config file as simple as possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the backslash, either individually with *another* backslash

```
re=foo\\.bar
```

or as part of a quoted string:

```
re='foo\.bar'
```

Comment: ... "without quoting the 'foo.bar' in the config file"

Comment: The question contains two constraints, sourcing the file and not modifying it, that are mutually incompatible. One of them needs to be violated; I chose the modifying the file, as the question didn't restrict the file to simple variable assignments. Replacing `source` could require re-parsing the file to handle arbitrary `bash` code, so modifying the file became the simpler option.

Comment: I have simplified my example too much; Actually it should be an array:

Comment: I have simplified my example too much; Actually it should be an array
containing many such expressions, each excluding file to skip in a back up.
I wanted the dots to be interpreted as an actual dot, not as any character.
I finally escaped the dots with \\ after sourcing, with:    `for i in
${!re[@]}; do re[$i]="${re[$i]//./\\\\.}"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Read it line by line:

```
IFS='='
while read -r var val
  do
    eval "$var=\"$val\""
  done < file.conf
```

Comment: Use `declare` instead of `eval` here, which will at least prevent the value of the variable from accidentally being evaluated as `bash` code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `read` loop with `-r` and `printf -v`:

```
while IFS=$' \t' read -r LINE; do
    [[ $LINE != \#* && $LINE =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*= ]] || continue
    IFS== read -r A B <<< "$LINE"
    printf -v "$A" "$B"
done
```

- We read the line as a whole first to get rid leading and trailing spaces.
- Comment-detection may also be an option but it's only easy for whole-line comments.